# Any idea why these DIVs are overlapping?

Tags: css, html

Can't for the life of my figure this one out...

Does anyone have any idea why the large red div at the bottom of this page is not flowing below the DIV above it, (but the red div is "appearing" behind it, and getting partially covered)?

I had the same problem with the ABOUT div at the top of the page flowing behind the div above it. The only way I could find to resolve it was to position:relative, and set the top to 45px. Same fix works here, but I would rather figure out why it is not flowing below the content above it than hack it. The Div above it has clearfix applied, and the issue doesn't seem to have anything to do with floats...other than that I am all out of ideas, and still fairly new to CSS...

http://firewalkcreative.com/2012/2012.html

Comment: So check it...if I do that, then I get the problem in the DIV above that one...

Answer (score 1):

The section (id="work") immediately above it has the styling 'position:relative;top:45px'. This moved it down 45px from where it would otherwise be, covering the top of the following section.

Comment: That's the one - remove the top: 45px; and you have your solution.

Comment: Just made that change, and reposted it..you can see that the problem then just goes further up: http://firewalkcreative.com/2012/2012.html

Comment: If you follow the problem up the page, it begins with a nav id="mainNav". It is 45px high and has position=absolute. Absolute positioning means that it's not included in the flow of the page. The other elements are positioned as though it wasn't there.

Comment: So I resolved it by adding an empty DIV and made it 45px high to account for the height of the nav bar...that seemed to solve the issue. But now, my links "ABOUT, WORK, CONTACT" link what seems to be 45px too low on the page... Any idea why that's happening or how to resolve it?